# XSL: Recursive call

Tags: xml, xslt

So I'm basically stuck at this part in my assignment which I'm unable to solve due to my noob skills in xml. 
This is a template in hdfunction.xsl:

```
 <xsl:template name="sumProduct">
    <xsl:param name="list1"/>
    <xsl:param name="list2"/>
    <xsl:param name="sumProductTotal" select="0"/>
 <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="count($list1) &gt; 0 and count($list2) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:call-template name="sumProduct">
            <xsl:with-param name="list1" select="$list1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="list2" select="$list2"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="sumProductTotal" select="current()/$sumProductTotal + $list1"/>      
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Another xsl which holds this related code:

```
  <xsl:include href="hdfunctions.xsl"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
     <html>
     <body>
     <p><xsl:value-of select="$subTotal"/></p>
     </body>
     </html>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="order[@custID='cust2222']"/>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="orders">
    <xsl:variable name="subTotal">
        <xsl:call-template name="sumProduct">
            <xsl:with-param name="list1" select="item/@qty"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="list2" select="item/@price"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
</xsl:template>
```

And finally xml document:

```
<orders>
  <order orderID="4122" custID="cust2222" orderDate="11/1/2017" shipping="8.95" tax="6.21">

  <item itemID="DH007" qty="1" price="74.99" />
  <item itemID="BD002" qty="3" price="40.99" />
  <item itemID="BH003" qty="1" price="21.99"/>
  <item itemID="DR002" qty="1" price="20.99"/>
  <item itemID="KR009" qty="1" price="53.99" />
  </order>
  </orders>
```

[image]

I can not get the variable $subTotal to hold any value, even when the template call from 2nd code shown above is replaced with "value-of select='item/@qty' it still returns with error.

Comment: "*iteration is human, recursion is divine*" Please post XML input code, and more of your XSLT to reproduce the problem and explain what are you stuck with.

Comment: @BurhanRizvi : where did you find an course on XSL that goes to this level? Thanks for any info.

Comment: @shellter I'm doing diploma and we're using 'New Perspectives on XML, Comprehensive, 3rd Edition'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to implement `sumProduct` template this way :

```
<xsl:template name="sumProduct">
    <xsl:param name="list1" />
    <xsl:param name="list2" />
    <xsl:param name="sumProductTotal" select="0"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count($list1) &gt; 0 and count($list2) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:call-template name="sumProduct">
                <xsl:with-param name="list1" select="$list1[position()&gt;1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="list2" select="$list2[position()&gt;1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="sumProductTotal" select="$sumProductTotal + $list1[1]*$list2[1]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sumProductTotal"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

**Brief explanation :**

- `select="$list1[position()&gt;1]"` : upon recursive call of the template, pass down all but the first element of `list1` parameter. The same rule applied for `list2` parameter.
- `select="$sumProductTotal + $list1[1]*$list2[1]"` : upon recursive call of the template, pass down current value of `sumProductTotal` plus value of product of the first element of current `list1` and `list2` parameter.
- `<xsl:value-of select="$sumProductTotal"/>` : when no more item in `list1` and `list2` parameter to be processed, simply return `sumProductTotal` value.

**Side note :**

`order` step is missing at the following part, because according to the sample XML, `item` is child of `order` while current context element here is `orders` :

```
<xsl:template match="orders">
    <xsl:variable name="subTotal">
        <xsl:call-template name="sumProduct">
            <xsl:with-param name="list1" select="order/item/@qty"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="list2" select="order/item/@price"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank alot for your response and explanation.
In the 2nd code and its 2nd line, template match is matching the root element which is 'orders'.
I however made a typing mistake which 'xsl:template match="orders"' where it actually should have been 'order' instead.

if the template match is changed to order, and apply template remains the same, it still shows me error when I try to retrieve an attribute value from order table using '@custID' for $subTotal select.

Comment: <xsl:template match="/">  
       <html>  
            <body>  
             <p><xsl:value-of select="$subTotal"/></p>  
            </body>  
        </html>  
     <xsl:apply-templates select="order[@custID=$customerID]"/>  
      </xsl:template>  
    
    <xsl:template match="order">  
  <xsl:variable name="subTotal">  
            <xsl:value-of select="@custID"/>   
       </xsl:variable>  
 </xsl:template>  

Are there any errors in this code?

Comment: @BurhanRizvi I don't know, that seems unrelated to this question (no call to `sumProduct` template there).

Comment: it is related because the call being made to template sumProduct is not retrieving the values from the parameters provided.
Your explanation for the code was really helpful and I believe the actual template code should work now. I just need a better understanding of why the parameters passed are not holding the desired value.
Once again thanks for your response mate.